# Set user setting value with another user setting value

Tags: c#, wpf, app-config, application-settings

If I create user setting variables called `var1` and `var2`, is it possible to put the value of var2 inside of var1?

For exemple:

[image]

```
Properties.Settings.Default.var2 = "stackoverflow";
Properties.Settings.Default.var1; // //path/stackoverflow/morepath
Properties.Settings.Default.var2 = "test";
Properties.Settings.Default.var1; // //path/test/morepath
```

Comment: You ask about settings variables, but show two data grid rows. It is not clear what you are asking. Please provide a minimal example of what you are doing, what the result is and what your expectation is.

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is no.

A string is just a string and there is no piece of built-in functionality that will dynamically replace `%var2%` in your first variable with the actual value of the second or any other variable.

If you want to somehow change the values of the variables, you will have to write some code that does this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Settings is essentially just an XML file, so there is no way you can dynamically inject a variable value into an entry.

However, you can achieve what you want at runtime by dynamically updating `var1` based on `var2`'s value using the `Properties.Settings.Default.Properties` object.

Here is an article that has some examples of dynamically updating entries:
https://codedocu.com/Net-Framework/WPF/Basics/Settings/WPF_colon_-Create,-write-and-read-settings-dynamically?2045

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Properties["var2"].DefaultValue  = "your updated value goes here"
```

Comment: I know I can update entries so I could search for `%` special character in the value of `var1`, and replace `%var2%` with the value of `var2` manually. But I wanted to know if there was a way to do it dynamically.

Comment: No, you cannot do it dynamically.